# How do I get a user input inside a `for in` loop

Tags: bash, read

I want to make the following script to prompt the user after each iteration, and wait for input before running the next iteration:

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR=$(pwd)

for f in $DIR/test-data/*.txt
do
    echo "$f"
    n=$(wc -w < "$f")
    k=$(( $n > 6 ? 6 : $n ))
    echo $n:$k
    java "Permutation" $k < "$f"
    read -p "Press Enter to continue"
done
```

The `read` command just prints the following and continues without pause:

```
Press Enter to continue./test.sh: 12: read: arg count
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX `read` doesn't have `-p`, that's a non-POSIX extension implemented in some shells (like bash). You're currently using `/bin/sh` which is probably a POSIX-compliant shell with limited extensions, if you want to use bash extensions you should consider using `/bin/bash` instead.

Instead, you can POSIXly do this:

```
printf 'Press Enter to continue'
read REPLY
```